# How to use bulk operations efficiently in cosmosdb with java MongoAPI?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to deal with bulk CRUD operations using java sdk for mongo API in cosmos db (like repository.saveAll(query), repository.deleteAll())).

By using these operations , the amount of RU's consumption is getting increased and finally it is giving rate limit error. Forcefully, for these operations I need to increase number of RU's for the container just to make the query successful.

Is there any way to deal with bulk operations without increasing the RU's ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for **Bulk Executor library** for Mongo API of Cosmos DB. *Unfortunately*, this feature is not out yet:

[image]

**Doc URL:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-java

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then how can we use saveAll or deleteAll query with the provisioned RU's. Is there any alternative way to handle large number of records ?

Comment: I can suggest you to do hit and trial method - try creating parallel threads for saving/deleting, parallelism of which will depend on the RUs you desire to set.